# Is there any way to kind of battery/panel was ordered just from looking at the OBR segment?

Tags: hl7

If I am looking at an OBR segment in HL7 -- is there any code/free text that explains what battery of tests is being performed? Place order number and filler order number don't seem right. OBR-31 reason for study explains why the panel was called -- not why standard battery was performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking for `OBR.4` value, Universal Service ID which contains the code and description of what panel or test are being ordered.
The panel will serve one single code and not the code of the component tests included in the panel.
[Read this](http://www.mexi.be/documents/hl7/ch400024.htm#E12E227) for more information

> 4.5.1.4 Universal service ID (CE) 00238

**Components:** `<identifier (ST)> ^ <text (ST)> ^ <name of coding system (ST)>`
`^<alternate identifier (ST)> ^ <alternate text (ST)> ^ <name of alternate coding system (ST)>`

**Definition:** This field is the identifier code for the requested observation/test/battery.This can be based on local and/or "universal" codes. We recommend the "universal"procedure identifier. The structure of this CE data type is described in the control section.